# How do I remove a pre-existing customizer setting?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

My theme doesn't use the tag line, how can I remove it from the customizer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Late to the party but this will do the trick:

```
$wp_customize->remove_control('blogdescription');
```

You want to remove just that control, not entire section as suggested above.

Comment: The setting should also be removed: $wp_customize->remove_setting('blogdescription')

Comment: Will this also remove any stored value that's currently in there? I'm having an issue where I want to delete existing setting/controls that have existing data, but the data is still being called back. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329343/why-is-remove-setting-and-remove-control-not-working

Answer (score 12):

Remove a pre exising customizer setting in wordpress theme with this code.

[image]

```
add_action( "customize_register", "ruth_sherman_theme_customize_register" );
function ruth_sherman_theme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

 //=============================================================
 // Remove header image and widgets option from theme customizer
 //=============================================================
 $wp_customize->remove_control("header_image");
 $wp_customize->remove_panel("widgets");

 //=============================================================
 // Remove Colors, Background image, and Static front page 
 // option from theme customizer     
 //=============================================================
 $wp_customize->remove_section("colors");
 $wp_customize->remove_section("background_image");
 $wp_customize->remove_section("static_front_page");

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found out the WP_Customize_Manager class has a function called `remove_section()`. In your function hooked to `customize_register` you can just do:

```
    $wp_customize->remove_section('nav');
    $wp_customize->remove_section('static_front_page');
```

You can find the ID of the section (i.e. 'nav') if you inspect the accordion title bar of the section. Look at the ID of the containing `<li>` tag and it's the portion of the string after `"customize-section-"`. I.E.:

```
<li id="customize-section-static_front_page" class="control-section customize-section">
```

-- the ID is `"static_front_page"`

Comment: That looks better than my solution so I will give you the tick - I haven't tested it but I suppose you have ... I don't get the title_tagline though - surely it should say static_front_page, is that a typo BAC?

Comment: @byronyasgur yep, that was a copy pasta error, fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this isn't the correct answer. This removes the _entire_ section that contains both the site title & tagline. The question is asking for only the tagline. Look at the answer below by @byronyasgur

Answer (score 3):

Accoring to [OTTO](http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/)

> One final thing you can add to a section is a “theme_supports” option.
>   This will make the menu not appear unless the theme supports
>   something. If you’re putting this code in a theme itself, then you
>   already know what the theme supports, so it doesn’t make much sense.
>   The core uses this to not show the header and background options if
>   the theme doesn’t support them.

So I put that together with

```
    $wp_customize->get_setting('blogdescription')->transport='postMessage';
```

... and discovered that the following code worked. I put `false` in for the theme_supports ... not sure what I really should be putting in ... maybe someone a bit more expert can improve on this.

```
    $wp_customize->add_control('blogdescription')->theme_supports=false;
```

Answer (score 2):

if the section / panel or control core , it is always better to disable them in place of removing.

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wp_stackexchange_58932' );
function wp_stackexchange_58932($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->get_section( 'static_front_page' )->active_callback = '__return_false';
    $wp_customize->get_section( 'custom_css' )->active_callback = '__return_false';
}
```

Comment: Great tip, i used it to always show the static_front_page setting, even if there is no page (by default it only shows when there is a page existing on the site)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this in a plugin you should use priority argument like 999 and it will work in the plugin.

```
add_action( "customize_register","wpcb_theme_customize_register",999,1);    

function wpcb_theme_customize_register($wp_customize){
   $wp_customize->get_setting('blogdescription')->transport='postMessage';
}
```

Comment: +1 for priority > 10. In my case I change customizer by a child theme. Without setting priority $wp_customize->get_setting() will return null since this function seems to be called before parent theme creates the setting.