# Removing pre existing menu item

Tags: theme-customizer

I want to remove the following items from the customizer menu:

[image]

However, I already tried a few codes [from other Stack questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58932/how-do-i-remove-a-pre-existing-customizer-setting) but with no luck!

Is it even possible to remove those?

Comment: You need to know the specific ID name, in order to successfully apply the `remove_control`or the `remove_section`command. Inspect the code to find it. In the link that you provide it's well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$wp_customize->remove_section('colors');
$wp_customize->remove_section('nav_menus');
$wp_customize->remove_section('static_front_page');
```

EDIT AFTER DISCUSSION

After testing I found that this doesn't work for `nav_menus`. You have to set a higher priority on the hook, like this:

`add_action( 'customize_register', 'remove_nav_menu_section', 20 );`

This gives a php warning from WP but otherwise does the job.

Comment: this removes the items from the image but Menu's is still there, any way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, it's `nav_menus`.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, or it's the code but the menu is still there.

Comment: If you use Chrome or Firefox you can right click on the item and choose 'inspect element'. You will get something like `<li id="accordion-section-nav_menus" .. >` Maybe it is not section but panel. Then you need `remove_panel`.

Comment: I tried inspecting it and it says "nav_menus", so it must be the right one - also when using `remove_panel`, it doesn't remove it either... the big Wordpress mystery..

Comment: Do you have any other solutions to fix it?

Comment: Looks like a mystery. Your theme or a plugin may be doing something with it and reinstall it.