# Remove Custuomize Sections

Tags: functions, theme-development, theme-customizer, theme-twenty-seventeen

I have followed the solution given [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58932/how-do-i-remove-a-pre-existing-customizer-setting) by Krupal Patel.

```
add_action( "customize_register", "ruth_sherman_theme_customize_register" ); 
function ruth_sherman_theme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

 //=============================================================
 // Remove header image and widgets option from theme customizer
 //=============================================================
  $wp_customize->remove_control( "header_image" );
  $wp_customize->remove_panel( "widgets" );

 //=============================================================
 // Remove Colors, Background image, and Static front page 
 // option from theme customizer     
 //=============================================================
  $wp_customize->remove_section( "colors" );
  $wp_customize->remove_section( "background_image" );
  $wp_customize->remove_section( "static_front_page" );

}
```

But I am unable to remove "Theme Options", "Menus" and "Header Media". Any help?

I am working on Twenty Seventeen.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to try is to increase the priority of your `customize_register` action from the default of `10` to something like `100`. The reason for this is other components add their sections and controls in the same action and some after `10`, so the things you are trying to remove may simply not have been added yet.

The second thing to note is that Widgets and Menus are a special case and they should not be disabled in this way. Instead, there is a dedicated filter you use to prevent them from getting loaded:

```
add_filter( 'customize_loaded_components', '__return_empty_array' );
```

For more see the [hook docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_loaded_components/).

See also my post on how to [reset the Customizer to a blank slate](https://make.xwp.co/2016/09/11/resetting-the-customizer-to-a-blank-slate/).

Answer (score 0):

Well besides the answer given by Weston, i tried the following commands. All of them worked except for the menu one.

```
   $wp_customize->remove_panel("nav_menus");
   $wp_customize->remove_panel("widgets");

   $wp_customize->remove_section('header_image');  //removes Header Media
   $wp_customize->remove_section('title');

   $wp_customize->remove_section("static_front_page");
   $wp_customize->remove_section("custom_css");
   $wp_customize->remove_section("title_tagline");
   $wp_customize->remove_section("colors");
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but for some reason the "Header Media" doesn't go away.

Comment: you tried with remove_section() ?